# How do I cancel out arrow key in Jquery

Tags: jquery, keyboard

I have this code which is for youtube autocomplete suggestions:

```
$(function(){

    $('#input-field').keyup(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        jQTubeUtil.suggest(val, function(response){
            var html = '';
            for(s in response.suggestions){
                var sug = response.suggestions[s];
                html += '<li class="li-class"><a href="#">'+sug+'</a></li>';
            }
            if (response.suggestions.length)
                $('#autocomplete').html(html).show();
            else 
                $('#autocomplete').hide();
        });
    });

});
```

How can I STOP a request being made if an arrow key (keycode 40/38) is being pressed?
I know it has something to do with '!' or event '.not' but my efforts did not pay off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply return, effecitvely halting the function execution, if the key is between those values.

```
$(function(){
    $('#input-field').keyup(function(event){
        if (event.which >= 38 && event.which <= 40)
            return;

        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: @Youss, If any of the answers to this question helped you, don't forget to choose it as the solution to your question by clicking the green checkmark next to it.

Comment: I know, but one has to wait for about 7min to accept, so I did the dishes in the meantime:)

Comment: Note that you wont be able to use your left or tight keys to navigate your text cursor with return;

Answer (score 2):

add an variable in: `$('#input-field').keyup(function(){` like `e`

```
$('#input-field').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode===38 /*Up key */ || e.keyCode === 40 /*key down */) { return ;}
    // Rest of your code...
```

Note that you may want to have a check for the left and right keys also, but dont prevent those but cancel out the call you are doing on "the rest of the code":

```
$(function(){

    $('#input-field').keyup(function(e){

        if(!(e.keyCode>=37 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
            var val = $(this).val();
            jQTubeUtil.suggest(val, function(response){
                var html = '';
                for(s in response.suggestions){
                    var sug = response.suggestions[s];
                    html += '<li class="li-class"><a href="#">'+sug+'</a></li>';
                }
                if (response.suggestions.length)
                    $('#autocomplete').html(html).show();
                else 
                    $('#autocomplete').hide();
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this to cancel a range of keys:

```
$(function(){
    $('#input-field').keyup(function(e){
        if (e.which >= 38 && e.which <= 40)
            e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```